# Proper way to update label with progress from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, winforms

I have a windows form program. In the main form I have a label where I update with progress. I use the following code to perform my operations:

```cs
Thread workThread = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        SliderOverBytesAndDoProcessing();
    }
});

workThread.Start();
```

The function `SliderOverBytesAndDoProcessing()` performs operations where I read 4 bytes and perform some operations on more bytes. I do this for each 4 bytes of the 200MB file (read 4 bytes process something and continue moving). Everything works fine until I decide to report my progress. Here is how I do the update:

```cs
Thread workThread = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        Lbl.Invoke((Action)delegate { Lbl.Text = "Processing " + (ii / 1048576) + "/" + (bytes.Length / 1048576); }
        SliderOverBytesAndDoProcessing();
    }
});

workThread.Start();
```

If I add that one line the program becomes too slow. I mean the program runs in around a few minutes without that line but with that line it takes around 1.5 hours. Also, on some other operations if I do that, I end up in infinite loops. How do I report my progress from the other thread to form thread without facing this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you’re a Java programmer. Consider using “normal” modern C# syntax (lambdas instead of delegates) and avoid the Java-ism of formatting text via `+`.

Comment: @Zastai Are you saying what is slowing down my program is my string concatenation using `+` operator?

Comment: No, just offering style suggestions which is why it’s a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is slow because you’re dispatching to the UI thread on every byte, even though the progress message only seems to care about megabytes. So you change the label over a million times to the same value.

Consider

```cs
var totalMb = bytes.Length / 1024 / 1024;
var lastMb = -1;

for (int i = 1; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
  var currentMb = i / 1024 / 1024;
  if (currentMb > lastMb) {
    Lbl.Invoke(() => { Lbl.Text = $"Processing {currentMb}/{totalMb} MiB" });
    lastMb = currentMb;
  }
  SliderOverBytesAndDoProcessing();
}
```

Comment: Typo: `1924` vs `1024`.  This will help a lot of course, but there's still a lot more room for improvement, such as using `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` (processing thread won't wait for GUI thread) and using `BackgroundWorker` component (which handles the `BeginInvoke` call for you)

Comment: Thanks Zatsai. I did not realize how much calls I was making and how expensive those calls were. I have used `if(i % 1048576 == 0)` and an increment counter within progress reporting line. Everything works as planned.

Comment: @BenVoigt Can I benefit from using `BeginInvoke` using `Thread`?

Comment: @LoranoDenka: Just change `Invoke` into `BeginInvoke`.  Both start off the same way (putting a message in the event queue of the GUI thread), but `Invoke` waits for the GUI update to complete and `BeginInvoke` doesn't wait.

Comment: @LoranoDenka: Queuing a message isn't free.  You still want to avoid sending the same (i >> 20) value a million times.  But yes, the waiting takes much more wall-clock time than the queueing.